# MySQL create table fails with varchar column

Tags: mysql

I cannot seem to get this to work no matter what I try.  I do not know if this is a bug or not, however I cannot find out that it isn't.

```
create table nonbinarystring (
tiny tinytext not null, 
normal text not null, 
large mediumtext not null, 
huge longtext not null, 
string char not null, 
varstring varchar not null);
```

I am just trying to create a table for a test database and this isn't a difficult issue... I don't understand why it is not working.

Thanks for all of the help in advance and I can only hope that I have not made a stupid mistake...

Comment: "*it is not working*" is not a valid MySQL error message

Comment: If the statement fails to execute, MySQL should be returning an error message which will include a four digit numeric code, a five character SQLSTATE value, and some error text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varchar requires a length parameter. 
Try specifying a length (max characters)

```
varstring varchar(20) not null);
```

Comment: I want to delete this question now... this was the answer... i figured like the other data types it would default to a max value. My mistake... i cant accept an answer yet but i will in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the length of varchar like this

```
varstring varchar(10) not null
```

here `10` will be the maximum number of characters that your field will accept.

or you can also use `max` as a parameter

```
varstring varchar(max) not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the size for **VARCHAR** datatype in MySQL.

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE nonbinarystring(
tiny TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
normal TEXT NOT NULL ,
large MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
huge LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
STRING CHAR NOT NULL ,
varstring VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
)
```